# Overwrite response header in Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

How can I overwrite previously set response header in Yesod? When I use the [`addHeader`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.4.35/docs/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v:addHeader) function, it adds another header with the same name instead of overwriting it. For example, if inside a handler function I do this:

```
addHeader "foo" "bar"
addHeader "foo" "baz"
```

I get

```
foo: bar
foo: baz
```

but I want to get just

```
foo: baz
```

In my case, the header is an authentication token, and it works in a way that if it's present in the request, then I send it back in the response. I implemented this as a middleware. However, if it's a login request, a new token is generated, and it should be sent instead of the value from the request header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addHeader` implementation by Writer.
https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.21/yesod-core-1.4.35/src/Yesod.Core.Handler.html#addHeaderInternal

It's not possible using `addHeader`.

It can be achieved by using [`sendWaiResponse`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.21/yesod-core-1.4.35/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v:sendWaiResponse) and creating `Response` by hand, but it's messy.